# Bamboo with Selenium - Read file on local file system

Tags: selenium, bamboo

I am trying to open `.html` file from local file system. When I run build on bamboo it fails to open file.

**error message**

> file not found

Path on local system

> file:///Users/xx/testing/framework/data/email/file_name.html

Path on Bamboo

> file:///Users/xx/testing/framework/data/email/file_name.html

Any ideas how I can fix this. Please let me know if you need any info.
Thanks

Comment: what is changing in the file path? both path look same

Comment: @TarunLalwani only home directory, which is being updated by `env` vairiable

Comment: Why don't you get the value of home environment variable in code and use it in the path?

Comment: @TarunLalwani I am, and is still failing to locate file.

Comment: Run `pwd` on bamboo and see where is the current folder located, the paths may not be same and try executing `ls -alh` to get the idea of the files present

Comment: @TarunLalwani I don't have access to machine, so I used `os.path.abspath("mydir/myfile.txt")` to find path on local machine, i.e.

> /Users/xx/testing/framework/data/email/file_name.html

on remote machine, file path is

> '/home/xxx/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/JOB1/reports/file_name.html'

This works on local machine and still does not work on remote machine. Error mesg: **file not found**